# How To Prevent Site Collections Being Created By Anybody But Tenant Admins

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, site-collection, microsoft-teams

We are seeing SharePoint Online site collections being created in our tenant by users who create Microsoft Teams areas/groups.  Teams automatically creates a site collection.  We want to apply governance to who can create site collections within our tenant but that doesn't seem to be possible.

We noticed these sites only after putting in an alert that surfaced when these sites were being created.

We do not officially use Microsoft Teams yet but it seems to be a security hole that allows non-admins to create site collections.

How can we only allow tenant admins to create site collections?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide [How to prevent users from creating and managing distribution groups in Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2580991/how-to-prevent-users-from-creating-and-managing-distribution-groups-in)

> > Step 1: Edit the default role assignment policy or create a new role assignment policy Depending on the particular scenario and the kind of
> >     organization, Exchange Online admins have two options for using a role
> >     assignment policy to control whether users can create and manage
> >     distribution groups. These options are as follows: If you want to
> >     apply the policy to all users in your organization, edit the default
> >     role assignment policy. If you have already created several role
> >     assignment policies or if you only want to disable this feature for a
> >     subset of users in your organization, create a new role assignment
> >     policy. Do one of the following things, as appropriate for your
> >     situation: Edit the default role assignment policy
>
> To edit the default role assignment policy, follow these steps: Sign
>   in to the Office 365 portal as an admin, click Admin, and then click
>   Exchange to open the Exchange admin center. In the left navigation
>   pane click permissions, and then click user roles. Double-click
>   Default Role Assignment Policy. Click to clear the
>   MyDistributionGroups check box and the MyDistributionGroupMembership
>   check box. Click Save. Create a new role assignment policy
>
> To create a new role assignment policy, follow these steps: Sign in to
>   the Office 365 portal as an admin, click Admin, and then click
>   Exchange to open the Exchange admin center. In the left navigation
>   pane click permissions, and then click user roles. Click New (A screen
>   shot of the New icon ). Type a name for the new role assignment
>   policy, and then click to select the options that you want. Make sure
>   that the MyDistributionGroups check box and the
>   MyDistributionGroupMembership check box are cleared. Click Save. Step
>   2: Apply the role assignment policy Important If you only use one role
>   assignment policy in your organization, you don't have to follow this
>   step.
>
> After you set up the role assignment policy, apply the policy. Be
>   aware that if you changed the default role assignment policy, you
>   don't have to reapply it. However, if you created a new role
>   assignment policy, you must apply it to users in your organization.
>
> To apply the role assignment policy, use one of the following methods,
>   as appropriate for your situation. Manually apply the role assignment
>   policy to one user by using the Exchange admin center
>
> To apply the role assignment policy to one user, follow these steps:
>   Sign in to the Office 365 portal as an admin, click Admin, and then
>   click Exchange to open the Exchange admin center. In the left
>   navigation pane, click recipients, and then click mailboxes.
>   Double-click the mailbox to which you want to apply the policy. In the
>   mailbox details window, click mailbox features, and then in the Role
>   assignment policy box, select the policy that you want to apply. Click
>   Save. Apply the role assignment policy to all users by using remote
>   PowerShell
>
> To apply the role assignment policy to all users in the organization
>   by using remote PowerShell, follow these steps: Connect to Exchange
>   Online by using remote PowerShell. For more information about how to
>   do this, see Connect to Exchange Online using remote PowerShell. At
>   the PowerShell prompt, type the following command, and then press
>   Enter:

```
Get-Mailbox | Set-Mailbox –RoleAssignmentPolicy “ <Name of
 Policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable group creation [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/manage-creation-of-groups?view=o365-worldwide) so that only people in a specific security group can create groups. Users won't be able to create teams (with a sitecolletion) anymore.

If you also disable site creation (SharePoint admin panel-->settings-->site creation) users won't be able to create sites.